# Data level Authorization filter in ASP.Net MVC Entity Framework application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, authorize

I was looking for a data level Authorization filter in my ASP.Net MVC 4 Application.
We are using Entity Framework for Data access.

The application need to display all the data but should restrict the access to certain fields in a table based on the user roles.

eg: TASK table
{
int Id,
string TaskName,
DateTime StartDate,
DateTime EndDate
}

This whole data will be displayed to all the users and users have the options to edit the fields also. But should restrict the edit options like as follows
Role Admin can edit all the fields
Role Manager can Edit TaskName but cannot edit StartDate and EndDate
Role Users cannot Edit any of the fields

All these edit will be calling the Edit action in the TaskController.

How can I implement the functionality in my application.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: If you know asp.net MVC applicastion you will be knowing that we can apply Authorization filter only at the action level not specific to data level. So whatever information I can provide I have explained here If you have any specific query please let me know.

Comment: It seems like you are stating a list of requirements and asking for a complete solution, a.k.a. `plzsendtehcodez`.  This site doesn't work that way.  See also http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: People who comes over here looking for codes and solutions and suggestion. If you go and look into the questions in the site most of them will be explaining the solution with the code and it will benefiting many other who are looking for similar solutions. There are few people like you gonna make this to an end by closing the questions like this.

Comment: @gvLearner - There's no such filter.  MVC and and Entity Framework are two separate libraries and while they complement each other pretty well, they are not related.  Since Filters are an MVC construct, Entity Framework doesn't know anything about them.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't know how you became moderator in this forum, You should view the response for this question. The question you have marked as Closed.

Comment: I was [elected by the community](http://stackoverflow.com/election).  The "what have you tried" rule is not my idea, it's the general consensus of the community.  I personally don't always agree with that rule, but I moderate based on community consensus and the site rules, not on my personal feelings or beliefs.  I'm glad you got an answer to your question, but the fact that you're calling this site a forum suggests that you don't fully understand how the site works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try Postsharp. PostSharp allows you to design custom attributes for injecting boilerplate code at compile-time. It should be possible to use it for scenarios such as your example. I've used it for exception handling, logging, caching, & security. It can be applied to any layer or framework.

See, "Securing Fields and Properties" in the following illustrated example:

http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/authorization

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is not EF, another ORM, but might help to see how it can be done - full source code is [here](https://vita.codeplex.com/).

Autorization subsystem is explained [here](https://vita.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=guide_authorization).

It does what you need - row-level, up-to-column granularity, role-based authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you are after is a true 'business' object that is smart and contains authorization at the property level not just at the method level.   I would suggest using CSLA.NET and create your business object model with smart objects.  This gives you that feature as well as a bunch of others.

Answer (score 0):

> This whole data will be displayed to all the users and users have the options to edit the fields also. But should restrict the edit options

Instead of a single Edit action in Task controller

1. create a specific action for each unique field set allowed to be edited

   - `Edit(TaskName, StartDate, EndDate)` for Admin
   - `Edit(TaskName)` for Manager
   - no `Edit` action for User, since ther are not allowed to change any fields
2. use [authorization per action](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16709853/2444725)