# Custom AuthorizeAttribute not being implemented

Tags: c#, authentication, authorization, authorize-attribute, asp.net-authorization

In our MVC solution we have two custom implementations of `AuthorizeAttribute` - one is named `BasicHttpAuthorizeAttribute` and has been used in production for years, and the other `RoleAuthorizeAttribute`, which was recently added.

When creating `RoleAuthorizeAttribute` I simply copied `BasicHttpAuthorizeAttribute` and modified some of the already-overridden methods.

Both attributes serve the purpose of authenticating the user, and the `RoleAuthorizeAttribute` of verifying that the user has the required role.

However, `RoleAuthorizeAttribute` never authenticates the user. It is simply not being called and instead our MVC controllers throw an exception when a non-logged-in user reaches the controller action and the code requests the context user.

Below is the outline for this custom `AuthorizeAttribute`. If I put breakpoints on all of those methods I find that none of them are hit when a request is made.

Can anyone explain why this class is not being used to authenticate users? Why is it that an unauthenticated user is not being redirected to the login page, but if I swap `RoleAuthorize` for `BasicHttpAuthorize` or simply the base `Authorize` then they *are* redirected?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]    
public class RoleAuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the <see cref="Role"/> enumerations required for authorization.
    /// </summary>
    public Role[] RequiredRoles
    {
        get {...}
        set {...}
    }

    public bool RequireSsl { get; set; };

    public bool RequireAuthentication { get; set; }

    public RoleAuthorizeAttribute(params Role[] requiredRoles)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // ...
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // ...
    }

    private bool Authenticate(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public static bool TryGetPrincipal(string authHeader, out IPrincipal principal)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public static bool TryGetAuthCookie(out IPrincipal principal)
    {
        // ...
    }

    private static string[] ParseAuthHeader(string authHeader)
    {
        // ...
    }

    private static bool TryGetPrincipal(string username, string password, out IPrincipal principal)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And here is an example of its usage:

```
namespace MyProject.Areas.Customer.Controllers
{
    [RoleAuthorize(Role.Customer, Role.CompanyAdmin)]
    public partial class OrderController : MyCustomController
    {
        private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (OrderController));

        public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

We use Basic Authentication so there's a header set thus:

[image]

I've seen [older questions asking about the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159317/custom-authorizeattribute-not-called), but in those cases, they also override an `AuthorizeCore` method which no longer seems to be present on the `AuthorizeAttribute` class.

Comment: how do you use this attribute? is there any other authorization filters in request pipeline? what is in your request headers?

Comment: Updated OP with the requested info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out myself why this was happening.

There are two `AuthorizeAttributes` - one in the `System.Web.Http` namespace and the other in `System.Web.Mvc`. I wasn't aware of this and was trying to build a one-size-fits-all attribute, so my attribute *was* working for WebAPI requests but not for MVC controller requests.

The difference in these two attributes is in the `OnAuthorize` method where they each take a different context argument.

Once I had built two separate attributes (which are almost identical), each deriving from a different `AuthorizeAttribute`, everything worked as expected.