# authorize whole controller to admin and 3 Actions inside to Admin and User Access level, how?

Tags: c#, authorization

I have AdminController which is authorize to Admin only with MVC attribute:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

I want 3 Actions inside the controller will be available to User access level also .

how can I do it ?

thank you

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403013/how-to-use-the-authorize-attribute-both-at-the-controller-and-action-level).

Answer (score 0):

got it :-)

this is what we need to put above the Actions:

```
[OverrideAuthorization]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,User")]
```