# How to cancel controller filter when action has a filter?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, attributes

I have a custom authorize filter that is on the controller and on some of the actions. The ones on the actions have parameters where the controller filter does not.  So, I want the controller filter to apply only to the ones that do not have that same filter with parameters.  I tried putting it on both places but the filter is called twice

```
    [CustomAuthorize]
    public class Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [CustomAuthorize(param1 ="123")]
        public ActionResult Index2()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

In the snippet above it calls customauthorize twice once with no parameters and second with parameters.

How do i prevent the first customauthorize if the action already has a customauthorize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea of attributes on controller is to apply this for each action. **So there are no possibility to run only action's attribute.** (there is if you remove class' ones)

[In this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709853/asp-net-mvc4-authorize-on-both-controller-and-action) it's quite well described when to use it.

Comment: so, in other words I have to give each action the filter and remove the class one?

Comment: If you want to use different attributes for different actions - Yes.