# how to override a custom filter attribute with action level validation while the class level validation is already declared in MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, filter, custom-attributes

My controller is using an attribute at class level which allows only one role to access. This controller has more than 20 actions. But for only one action I need one more role to get access. I have declared the attribute filter at class level so that it is working fine for all the actions within the controller class. But now I want to override this one for only one action within the same controller. Is there any possibility for that?  I'm using .Net version 4.5.

Filter attribute implementation goes like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class RequireModulePermissionAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
   //code goes here
}
```

Controller class:

```
[RequireModulePermission("Admin")]
public class AdministrationController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [RequireModulePermission("Admin","Supervisor")]
    public ActionResult CreateUser(UserViewModel userVM)
    {
       //code goes here
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this answer (look at case 2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/16713334/2564920

Essentially you will need a second attribute to represent the override.

So you attributes become:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class RequireModulePermissionAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            var action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor;
            if (action.IsDefined(typeof(OverrideRequireModulePermissionAttribute ), true)) return;
            //code goes here
        }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class OverrideRequireModulePermissionAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
       public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
       {
           base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
       }
    }
```

The you use it like

```
[RequireModulePermission("Admin")]
public class AdministrationController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [OverrideRequireModulePermission("Admin","Supervisor")]
    public ActionResult CreateUser(UserViewModel userVM)
    {
       //code goes here
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an alternative that you can actually set AllowMultiple = false.

In this way, only 1 filter will take effect following the filter execution order: Global -> Controller -> Action.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not accurate. `AllowMultiple = false` disallows having multiple attributes on the same action/controller. You still can add one filter to a controller and the same filer to an action. *All such filters* will take effect, following the *default* filter execution order: Global -> Controller -> Action. `AllowMultiple` has no effect on this behaviour