# ASP.NET MVC: Override authorization filter roles for single action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an Authorization Filter that annotates a controller class like so:

```
[Authenticated(Roles = "read_mail", "contact_user")]
public class MailController : Controller { ... }
```

However there is one action where the user needs to only one permission:

```
[Authenticated(Roles = "read_mail")]
public ActionResult Inbox() { ... }
```

As it's currently set up,  only the filter that annotates the class is acknowledged and does the appropriate redirect. Is there a way to override it just for specific action or should I remove the filter from the controller and define it for every action instead? ﻿

Comment: yes, apply it on action level on that controller

Answer (score 1):

You can influence the order in which filters are applied as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx). For your use case adding `Order` to your attributes probably does the trick:

```
[Authenticated(Roles = "read_mail", "contact_user", Order = 1)]
public class MailController : Controller { ... }

[Authenticated(Roles = "read_mail", Order = 0)]
public ActionResult Inbox() { ... }
```

The filter with the lowest `Order` will run first.

**Edit**

I just found out the `Order` won't do much good. Both filters still get executed (only in reversed order). To override the filter at controller level: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16713334/502395).