# MVC - dynamic role management

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, custom-attributes, action-filter, asp.net-roles

I have users that have one of those roles:

- RoleA (Attribute: AuthorizeRoleA)
- RoleB (Attribute: AuthorizeRoleB)

In my controller I want to say this:

Everyone that has role of type *RoleA* 
can access all the methods in this controller

```
[AuthorizeRoleA]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
        public ActionResult MethodOne()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult MethodTwo()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //****** Make an exception ********
        //So in this case, let RoleA here, but let RoleB too.
        [AuthorizeRoleB] 
        public ActionResult MethodThree()
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```

And I have another controller:

Everyone that has role of type *RoleB* 
can access all the methods in this controller

Just *RoleB*! No one else.

```
[AuthorizeRoleB]
public class AnotherController : Controller
{
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```

So, this should be similar with the `Authorize` attribute when is used to decorate the controller, and the `AllowAnonymous` when is used inside the same controller, but I don't know how to achieve this behavior with custom attributes(filters).

My goal is to create custom attributes, where I can say:
In `AuthorizeRoleA` will be included n-roles
and in `AuthorizeRoleB` will be included n-other roles.
But `AuthorizeRoleA` will have highest priority than the other attributes.

*Note: Maybe this is a duplicate, but I didn't find anything similar to this question.*

Comment: In Autorize attribute you can specify role, [Authorize(Roles="RoleA")]

Comment: Optionally it can be used like this, if you want to allow more than one role
[Authorize(Roles="RoleA, RoleB")]

Comment: @DanielVorph consider this answer (case 1): 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16713334

Comment: @nocturns2 yes, it was the first thing that pops in my mind, but I have n-controllers and n-actions, and I want to avoid that writing on every action/controller. Also in the future I might have n-roles, so than I'll have to rewrite all the Authorize attributes

Comment: your question is about Method three in HomeController ?

Comment: http://bitoftech.net/2015/03/31/asp-net-web-api-claims-authorization-with-asp-net-identity-2-1/