# C# Authorize Attribute Logic

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to implement the `Authorize` attribute in my WebApi Controllers. I've found resources on how to implement `Authorize`, and even that I need to set the Thread and HttpContext Principals when implementing Authorization. But I can't find an example of how/where I write the Authorization logic.

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get() {}
}
public class MyAuthorizationProvider
{
    public void AuthorizeIGuess()
    {
        string authHeader = HttpContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("Authorization").FirstOrDefault();

        // do stuff with auth header
        // create principal

        HttpContext.Current.User = ...;
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = ...;
    }
}
```

How do I setup `MyAuthorizationProvider` so that it is used for `Authorize`, and is this how I set my auth context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inherit `AuthorizeAttribute` like

```
public class MyAuthorizationProvider : AuthorizeAttribute  
{
  //Write your validation logic here. 
}
```

and use this override authorization attribute like

```
    public class MyController : ApiController
  {
    [Route("")]
    [MyAuthorizationProvider]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get() {}
  }
```

When you inherit `AuthorizeAttribute`, it will gives you some override method to implement your logic in better way, use that also. For more details [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709853/asp-net-mvc4-authorize-on-both-controller-and-action/16713334#16713334).

Comment: In examples where simply `[Authorize]` is used are those just abstract examples? Is it possible to reuse the `[Authorize]` attribute or is it always extended/renamed?