# Get MVC AllowAnonymous to override custom authorize attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created a custom authorize attribute, but I need some actions to allow anonymous access.  I've tried three different approaches without success: use `AllowAnonymous`, update the existing attribute with additional parameters, and create a new overriding attribute.  Basically it seems that the controller-level attribute always gets called before the action-level attribute.

Here's the controller:

```
[AuthorizePublic(Sites = AuthSites.Corporate)]
public class CorporateController : SecuredController
{
    [AuthorizePublic(Sites = AuthSites.Corporate, AllowAnonymous = true)]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
}
```

And the attribute:

```
public class AuthorizePublic : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public AuthSites Sites { get; set; }
    public bool AllowAnonymous { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // Logic
    }        
}
```

As a last resort I can move the login actions onto their own controller, but before I do that, am I missing something to get one of these approaches to work?  I'm a bit surprised that action-level attributes aren't overriding controller-level attributes.

Comment: Just to confirm, a simple `[AllowAnonymous]` on an Action method does not override the Authorization attribute in your case?

Comment: Confirmed. If I debug, I can see it's hitting the controller attribute and getting stuck in a redirect loop.

Comment: So the problem seems not to be the Authorization, but the redirect loop - which should not happen. Care to fill in some details on that in your question? Maybe shopw us the code of your AuthorizeCore method, or whatever is causing that redirect

Comment: I hear your theory, but I just removed the attribute on the controller, and the custom attribute on the action is being completely ignored.  Maybe I need to update my attribute implementation to indicate that it can be used for actions as well?

Comment: You can also try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16713334/2218697) answer. May be helpful.

Comment: Using .Net 4.5.2. I've tried inheriting from both versions of `AuthorizeAttribute` (Http and Mvc) without success.

Comment: We really could do with your full implementation of your AuthorizePublic class to reproduce this. Or a dumbed down version of it in any case. At least something we can copy paste into our own sandboxes to see whats what.

Comment: You can just put `return true` in there.  The problem is that the attribute is not being hit at action level.  Additionally it seems that there are two AuthorizeAttribute classes you can inherit from, so the various code examples differ.

Comment: In other words, the fact there is a redirect loop is a red herring - the real issue is that I'm unable to override the custom attribute defined on the controller, which is why it's looping on itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the implementation of the [`OnAuthorization` method of  `AuthorizeAttribute`](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs#L94-L95) that scans for `AllowAnonymousAttribute`. So, you must either *not override* this method or re-implement this check if you want that part to work. Since you have only provided a cut-down implementation of `AuthorizeAttribute`, it cannot be assumed that you are not overriding this method (and thus overriding the logic that makes the check).

Also, your example controller *doesn't actually show usage of the `AllowAnonymousAttribute`*. Instead, it sets a property named `AllowAnonymous`. If you expect anonymous users to reach that action method, you should decorate it with the attribute that MVC is actually scanning for.

```
[AuthorizePublic(Sites = AuthSites.Corporate)]
public class CorporateController : SecuredController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you need to customize the `AllowAnonymous` behavior in some way, you can keep using the property you have, but you have to implement the Reflection code yourself to scan for `AuthorizePublic` and check the `AllowAnonymous` property.

```
public class AuthorizePublic : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public AuthSites Sites { get; set; }
    public bool AllowAnonymous { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var actionDescriptor = httpContext.Items["ActionDescriptor"] as ActionDescriptor;
        if (actionDescriptor != null)
        {
            AuthorizePublic attribute = GetAuthorizePublicAttribute(actionDescriptor);
            if (attribute.AllowAnonymous)
                return true;

            var sites = attribute.Sites;

            // Logic
        }
        return true;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // Pass the current action descriptor to the AuthorizeCore
        // method on the same thread by using HttpContext.Items
        filterContext.HttpContext.Items["ActionDescriptor"] = filterContext.ActionDescriptor;
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }

    // Gets the Attribute instance of this class from an action method or contoroller.
    // An action method will override a controller.
    private AuthorizePublic GetAuthorizePublicAttribute(ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        AuthorizePublic result = null;

        // Check if the attribute exists on the action method
        result = (AuthorizePublic)actionDescriptor
            .GetCustomAttributes(attributeType: typeof(AuthorizePublic), inherit: true)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        if (result != null)
        {
            return result;
        }

        // Check if the attribute exists on the controller
        result = (AuthorizePublic)actionDescriptor
            .ControllerDescriptor
            .GetCustomAttributes(attributeType: typeof(AuthorizePublic), inherit: true)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        return result;
    }
}
```

`AuthorizeAttribute` implements both `Attribute` and `IAuthorizationFilter`. With that in mind, the `IAuthorizationFilter` part of `AuthorizeAttribute` is a **different runtime instance of the class** than the `Attribute` part. So the former must use Reflection to read the property of the latter in order for it to work. You can't just read the `AllowAnonymous` property from the current instance and expect it to work, because you are setting the value in the attribute and the code is executing in the filter.

> MVC and Web API are completely separate frameworks with their own separate configuration even though they can co-exist in the same project. MVC will completely ignore any controllers or attributes defined in Web API and vise versa.

Comment: A detailed explanation, thanks - overriding the reading of the attributes did the trick for me