# How can i stop a user from browsing to a View in MVC by typing link in the browser?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have an MVC app which has the following route config

In Global.ascx

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

In the RouteConfig.cs I have

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
    
Now if i type in the browser , https://localhost/users this will take me to the 
UsersController and call the Index() ActionResult. In there i do a check to see if the 
user has access to the view or not as follows:

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (<User has access condition check>)
        {
            return View();
        }
        return View("~/Views/PermissionError.cshtml");
    }
```

The issue is that I have about 30 pages in my app that the user can browse to by typing in the broswer url.
So instead of doing the check in every Index ActionResult , is there a way i can do the check in my route config or somewhere else that does the permission check and if they are allowed to view the page it will continue to the page
else it will show the error page ?

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way i can do the check in my route config or somewhere else that does the permission check

Yes, that might write a customer [`AuthorizeAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) to make it.

You can try to write a customer `AuthorizeAttribute` and register that to global filter setting.

Here is the sample code which you can edit by your real logic.

```
public class AuthorizeBrowsingAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
       var isAnonAllowed = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(
            typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true) || 
        filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(
            typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true);

        // user did't get 
        if (!<User has access condition check> && !isAnonAllowed)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Views/PermissionError.cshtml");
        }
    }
}
```

The code register our customer `AuthorizeAttribute`

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new AuthorizeBrowsingAttribute());
}
```

If there are some page which you don't want to do permission check you can add `AllowAnonymous` attribtue on the view method.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult NoPermission()
{
}
```

Comment: thanks for that but im a bit confused as to how to add it all in my app. Is there by any chance a sample app in c#

Comment: @Kelly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: i cant seem to get it going, so i guess i may have to implement in all 30 ActionResults. I know its not elegant.

Comment: @Kelly You don't need to implement it in all 30 ActionResults just hang up on the global filter, it will be work for 30 ActionResults

Comment: At the moment if a user logs in , i read their settings from a db and when for example i go to the userdetails ActionResult I read that setting and if true i display the View() else i display the errors page. Now for all the other views their will be different options that i must read .

Comment: thats what i cant really see how the global filter will do it . sorry i havent used it before , trying to understand its functionality.  Every day is a learning day i guess .

Comment: @Kelly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709853/asp-net-mvc4-authorize-on-both-controller-and-action/16713334